# Custom bootstrap jquery slider with parts of image

Tags: jquery, slider

Could someome tell me if it is possible to achieve this kind of slider (not sure if it's called a slider though) with bootstrap & jquery?
Demo on this site: http://www.webhelp.com/uk/

Thank you.

Comment: This is a slider that they have designed them even

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know, I was just wondering if it would be possible to do the something similar with bootstrap and jquery

Comment: Created this fiddle, you can get inspired : https://jsfiddle.net/fjwjy74j/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out.

Comment: Vertical slider is available in bootstrap http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/vertical-slider